# How to Delete Record selected columns from table using checkbxes

Tags: angularjs

Here I'm displaying some amount of data in the table. My aim is when I select some checkboxes I want to delete that row. Please, help me, I can't make it work.

**Htmlcode**

```
<div ng-controller="EmpCtrl">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" ng-show="GetDb.length>0">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input name="all" type="checkbox" ng-click="selectAllFriends()" />
            </th>
            <th>Id</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="ee in GetDb" ng-class="{'success' : tableSelection[$index]}">
            <td>
                <input name="all" type="checkbox" ng-model="ee.checked" ng-true-value="{{ee.id}}" />

            </td>
            <td>{{ee.id}}</td>
</div>
```

**Controller.Js**

```
$scope.remove = function() {
    $scope.deletedIds = [];
    $scope.GetDb.forEach(function (x) {
        if (x.checked) {
            $scope.deletedIds.push(x)
        }
    }
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete, you don't have maintain separate copy of ('deletedIds') those you want to delete, just delete it the way below-

```
$scope.remove=function(){
     $scope.GetDb.forEach(function (x,index) {
        if (x.checked) {
            $scope.GetDb.splice(index,1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh you were keeping mind in server side too, then go with you were doing passing that paramer to MVC after success of removal from DB then call again for fetching desired details,

Comment: I thought you were asking about on client side itself.

Comment: you need to make HTTP request for it for passing the details and have to implement that way

Comment: you could find as many as example for making http request call in angularjs as long as you have your API ready to support your desired result

Comment: if u have any urls plz send me

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution-

```
<div ng-controller="EmpCtrl">
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" ng-show="GetDb.length>0">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input name="all" type="checkbox" ng-click="selectAllFriends()" />
                </th>
                <th>Id</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="ee in GetDb" ng-class="{'success' : tableSelection[$index]}">
                <td>
                    <input name="all" type="checkbox" ng-model="ee.checked" ng-true-value="{{ee.id}}" ng-change="delete($index)"/>

                </td>
                <td>{{ee.id}}</td>
    </div>


$scope.delete = function(index){
    delete $scope.GetDb[index].checked;
    delete $scope.GetDb[index].id;
};
```